# web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Springmvc/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Helloweb'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

On running the Spring MVC Application, I am facing a 404 error.
Can someone please help on this.

Details :
Project structure :
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wW3Y.png)

web.xml
[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgySd.png)

Helloweb-servlet.xml
[Helloweb-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYkxy.png)

hello.jsp
[hello.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6nhb.png)

HelloController.java
[HelloController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5MYD.png)

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bxZw.png)

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Springmvc/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Helloweb'

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Springmvc/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Helloweb'

Tomcat version :  Apache Tomcat/9.0.85

Note : mvc:default-servlet-handler/ in Helloweb-servlet.xml did not solve the issue

Comment: Please don't post code as links to images. Instead include the code in your question with proper code tags.